# How to prevent images from reloading when leaving "display: none"

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, ember.js

I am writing an Ember.js web-application, designed to be the user interface of an automation system, that polls data from the LAN server every two seconds in order to have on display always the "live" process data.
This application is accessible from a wirless hotspot, to allow registered users to browse it, so potentially any device (tablets, smartphones, laptops...) could be the actual client.

On some pages, there are icons that change according to some conditions, and to implement this effect I declared several `img` tags, and I make the ones I dont need invisible by styling it with CSS `display: none`.

In HTML:

```
<img class="icon-active" src="/images/icon1.jpg" />
<img class="icon-inactive" src="/images/icon2.jpg" />
```

In Javascript, every two seconds:

```
var visibleElement = null;
var invisibleElement = null;

if( this.get("whatever").active == true )
{
    visibleElement = this.element.getElementsByClassName("icon-active")[0];
    invisibleElement = this.element.getElementsByClassName("icon-inactive")[0];
}
else
{
    visibleElement = this.element.getElementsByClassName("icon-inactive")[0];
    invisibleElement = this.element.getElementsByClassName("icon-active")[0];
}

visibleElement.style.display = null;
invisibleElement.style.display = "none";
```

Everything works fine, on laptops and tablets, but on some smarthphones, the images are loaded every time I set `visibleElement.style.display = null;`, it means, every two seconds, the visible icon is GETted again and again from server.

I dont want it to happen at first to reduce data traffic, that is not a problem at all, but I don't like fetching resources even if not required, second, the image reload generates an annoying flicker effect, that is really unlookable.

How can I force every client to cache images as tablets and laptops do?

----- more info -----

Thanks everyone for your support! Here you have some news:

I tried as suggested to comment-out all the javascript code that works on `style.display` and modify the HTML (template) as follows:

```
{{#if whatever.active}}
    <img class="icon-active" src="/images/icon1.jpg" />
{{else}}
    <img class="icon-inactive" src="/images/icon2.jpg" />
{{/if}}
```

and I got **the same result**. So I tried to roll back the HTML and leave the javascript commented, in such way I should have always all the icons visible, and surprise... they are all flickering and being requested every two seconds...

I guess the issue is due to the fact that some (maybe not up-to-date?) smartphone browsers are redrawing completely the images as the ember-views bound data gets updated. I will investigate more on which browser/version has this problem and make sure all of the testing devices use the last version of their browsers - since ember uses the latest javascript features, better cut-out old fashioned clients.

The code used to refresh data every two seconds follows, please notify if you see anything uncommon:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        // record generation code here...
    },

    afterModel()
    {
        Ember.run.later(this, function()
            {
                this.refresh();
            }
        , 2000);
    }
});
```

**----- solution -----**

With new up-to-date browsers is not happening, so, this behavior exists only "in the past"... For sake of completeness I should find a solution to make it work properly also on "old" browsers, but I don't have time to spend on this.

If anyone of you figures out a 360 degrees solution an answer is still appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using display block / inline-block / inline instead of null?  If that fails then you could try adding removing a class to show / hide the image - I've never seen an image re-downloaded when just changing the display property before though, only when the src is changed

Comment: @Pete is right. A image won't get redownloaded if you set your `display: none;` only when you would remove your `img` out of the DOM.

Comment: Server is logging a GET request to the image resource at every flicker when opening the page with android and iPhones too.

Comment: @Pete I just tried to change <null> with "display: inline" but still, flicker and GET images every time the style display field value is re-written, but I repeat, this happens only on some smartphones, is it possible that "that browser" for "that OS" just behave in a "strange" way? If so, I should think about a completely different approach maybe.

Comment: Have you tried to not use CSS for this but an ember `{{#if}}`? This would at least keep everything you need out of the DOM. Next, check your cache headers on the image, and verify this happens if you're not in developer mode. And next you want to change the image every 5 seconds or not? Because if not, ember would not change anything until you do.

Comment: I feel the same, your page might have css styles for images and later you are changing their display can cause flicker if js is taking time to load. It's better to use `{{#if}}` on some condition as @Lux mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As I see those icons are static. So my suggestion is to use css:

1) Use spans(or divs) instead if images
2) Add icon as background image

html:

```
<p><span>active parameter</span><span class="icon active"></span></p>
<p><span>inactive parameter</span><span class="icon inactive"></span></p>
```

css:

```
.item
    width: 16px //icon dimensions
    height: 16px 
    // you may also add display: inline same as for images and so on

.active
    background-image: url('/images/icon1.jpg')

.inactive
    background-image: url('/images/icon2.jpg')
```

Benefit: Images will be loaded once by css engine along with styles.

PS: You can get rid of `inactive` class if your icon is inactive by default:

html:

```
<p><span>active parameter</span><span class="icon active"></span></p>
<p><span>inactive parameter</span><span class="icon"></span></p>
```

css:

```
.item
    width: 16px //icon dimensions
    height: 16px 
    background-image: url('/images/icon2.jpg')
    // you may also add display: inline same as for images and so on

.active
    background-image: url('/images/icon1.jpg')
```

PPS: It's really easy to manage classes with Ember by using [classNameBindings](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the image display to **none**.

Set the display to either inline-block or block for visible and none for not visible.

Preferably use css classes, since you are doing it with javascript. It might delay the action of hiding the images while the page loads.

You can use css classes like

```
.active{
    display:block;
}

.inactive{
    display:none;
}
```

Use these classes to add or toggle for a specific img element.

Still there will requests to server for images because you are only hiding the images through styles.

[Display MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: "visibleElement.style.display = null;" means for the browser "use the default setting for this element's display mode"

Comment: Use `visibleElement.style.display = "";` instead of null